# how to link css and js in laravel

Tags: laravel, hyperlink

Could you tell me how to link css and js file in laravel according to my file structure
I wanna link app.css and app.js into museum.blade.php (inside portfolio)

I have try something like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('resources/css/app.css')}}">`, but it did not work

here is my file structure

[image]

please help me, thank you so much

Comment: i see a ">" for app.css is it because that's a folder? if yes then i think `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('resources/css/app.css/app.css')}}">` and if i am not mistaken, you are supposed to but it in the public folder not resources folder

Comment: For any CSS and JS that is under resources you need to check [compiling assets](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix). If you don't want to compile them then put them under your `/public` folder

Answer (score 2):

> I have try something like this: , but it did not work

This happens because **resources folder** are not to be consumed "public", the folder that would be consumed by "public" is a **public folder**, you need to compile them from resource to public first. Laravel has great documentation about it at [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix)

To fix your problem, you need to find a file on your project directory called "webpack.mix.js"

and put this mix code on it.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/js/museum.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

and then you can run `npm run dev` at your command line to compile the assets.

it will compile your targeted resources on webpack mix to public.

After that, on the head of your museum.blade.php, you can call it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project has Vite installed, you can put `@vite(['resources/css/app.css','resources/js/app.js'])` in your `welcome.blade.php` file.

When creating a Laravel project using Composer, for Laravel framework version 10+ (not sure if exists in previous versions), you should also find a `vite.config.js` in the main parent directory. Using Node.js, do `npm install` then Vite should automatically be installed and available to use as specified above.

Answer (score 0):

First Step : Make a folder called css in public folder
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnFxc.png)

Second Step : Put your css file here (like public/css/style.css)

Third Step : link it using this code in your html code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
```

Enjoy !